# c# How to get attribute name from xslt

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I have following part of xslt in string format :-

```
<xsl:if test="TestValue3 and TestValue3 != ''">
                                                <xsl:attribute name = "TestDate" >
                                                <xsl:value-of select = "TestValue3" />
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                </xsl:if>
```

I just want to fetch its attribute name from c# code.

```
Attribuute Name= TestDate
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input ?

Comment: The xslt you had provided is not enough to generate answer for you. so please provide appropriate or full xslt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your favourite XML API to load the XSLT and iterate/query the item in question (in this case you would need to look for the owning `xsl:if` and the condition itself).  e.g. you could load it into an [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xdocument-class-overview).

You can use `XPath` to find the element for `XmlDocument`s or if you use `XDocument` you can use *LINQ*.

Do not attempt to use technologies that are not equipped for structured data.

i.e.

- **don't** use *flat string search*
- **don't** use *regex*

> Actually I am adding above block into existing xslt ,, but before adding I need to check if attribute name =TestDate already exists ... For that I need to know attribute name , becase attribute name can vary as per block,, it is not fix each time

Again, use the above recommendations.  Both `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` allow for load/edit/save.

Comment: Actually I am adding above block into existing xslt ,, but before adding I need to check if attribute name =TestDate already exists ... For that I need to know attribute name , becase attribute name can vary as per block,, it is not fix each time

Comment: @CSharper OK, well the above can do that too.  Don't try doing anything with C# string append or something.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly this should do the job, otherwise please add more context.

```
<xsl:if test="TestValue3 and TestValue3 != ''">
  <xsl:if test="not(@TestDate)">
    <xsl:attribute name = "TestDate" >
      <xsl:value-of select = "TestValue3" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```